# Repeating a whole algorithm

Tags: python-3.x

I am a real newbie to Python, I am taking it for GCSE at my school and I have been given an assignment to complete. I completed all of the requirements for this simple code but am not sure how to repeat it. Could someone please show me a simple way of repeating the code?

Thanks

```
import random

Random = random.randint(1,100)

Guess = int(input("Please guess a number between 1 and 100: "))

counter = 1

while Guess != Random:
    if Guess > Random:
        print("Too high")
        Guess = int(input("Please guess the number: "))
    else:
        print("Too low")
        Guess = int(input("Please guess the number: "))
    counter += 1

print("Well Done:")
print("You took:",counter, "Guesses")
```

Comment: What do you mean by repeat the code? Do you want the game to restart automatically?

Comment: Hint: you are already using a technique that causes code to repeat. How can you utilize `while` to achieve your objective?

Comment: Repeat it until when?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way of doing it would be to put it in a while True loop with a conditional break:

```
import random


while True:
    Random = random.randint(1,100)

    Guess = int(input("Please guess a number between 1 and 100: "))

    counter = 1


    while Guess != Random:
        if Guess > Random:
            print("Too high")
            Guess = int(input("Please guess the number: "))
        else:
            print("Too low")
            Guess = int(input("Please guess the number: "))
        counter += 1

    print("Well Done:")
    print("You took:",counter, "Guesses")

    choice = input("Would you like to continue? y/n")
    if choice == "n":
        break
```

Note, randint(1,100) will return a number from 1-99 inclusive, and you are actually asking the user for a guess 2-99 inclusive the way you have phrased it.